# Spark Structured Streaming Foreach Batch to Write data to Mounted Blob Storage Container

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am receiving streaming data and wanted to write my data from Spark databricks cluster to Azure Blob Storage Container.

To do this I have mounted my storage account and I am specifying my path into my streaming sink query.

**Method 1**

```
dataframe.writeStream\
    .format("text")\
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/Checkpoint")\
    .option("path", "/mnt/Data")\
    .start()
```

**Method 2**

```
def process_row(df, epoch_id):
    try:
        df.write\
            .format("text")\
            .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
            .option("path", "/mnt/Data")\
            .save()
        
    except (Exception) as error:
        print("Received an error ",error)
  

dataframe.writeStream.outputMode('append')\
    .foreachBatch(process_row).option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/Checkpoint").start()
```

*Using Method 1, I am able to write data to blob container.
But using Method 2, data is not getting written to blob storage, nor it's displaying some error.*
Method 2 Query Dashboards shows me something like this :

[Method 2 Query Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PryPB.png)

Am I missing something in Method 2's code?

Answer (score 0):

I think foreachBatch is used when you want to, say, process each batch in more than one way or write to more than one location  so if you want exception handling I would just put method 1 in your try-catch.

For curiosity sake if you want to use foreachBatch maybe try just `.writeStream` within scope and not have any `write` method outside so you leave the write call to the `foreachBatch` function.

Something like (not tested).

```
def process_row(df, epoch_id):
    try:
        df.writeStream\
        .format("text")\
        .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
        .option("path", "/mnt/Data")\
        .option("checkpointLocation","/mnt/Checkpoint")\
        .outputMode(“append”)\
        .start()
   
    
    except (Exception) as error:
        print("Received an error ",error)


dataframe.foreachBatch(process_row)
```